# Outlook VBA to verify recipient

Tags: vba, outlook

What is the best way to check for multiple black-list email addresses before sending?

I have several email addresses I am not allowed to send information to as part of a project. I want Outlook to check for any of the black-list email addresses and notify me if they are included before sending. Below is the code I found to modify

For example, my black-list includes: "bad@address.com", "worst@address.com", "evil@address.com"

What is the best way to put these addresses into the code below, would be good for it to be in a way that allows for changing the addresses in the black-list easily?

So here is the latest version of my code with your suggestions. Unfortunately it lets me send the emails to the addresses on the Checklist. Any suggestions?

```
  Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim Recipients As Outlook.Recipients
  Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
  Dim i
  Dim prompt As String


On Error Resume Next
 ' use lower case for the address
 ' LCase converts all addresses in the To field to lower case

  Checklist = "bad@address.com" & _
            "worst@address.com" & _
            "evil@address.com" '// , _ and so on

 Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
  For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set recip = Recipients.Item(i)

 If InStr(LCase(recip), LCase(Checklist)) Then
      prompt$ = "You sending this to this to " & Item.To & ". Are you sure you want to send it?"
       If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
         Cancel = True
       End If
  End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: select an answer to say if this can be closed. Keep SO clean, and let us not inflate unanswered question count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a procedure level variable **CheckList** which is the list of csv of black listed emails. you can initialise this in the procedure as a hard assignment or dynamically retrieve from other data sources for e.g. sql server

```
Dim lbadFound  As Boolean
dim badAddresses as string
lbadFound = False

CheckList = "bad@address.com," & _
            "worst@address.com," &  _
            "evil@address.com" '// , _ and so on

    Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
    For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
      Set recip = Recipients.Item(i)

      If instr(1,lcase(CheckList),  LCase(recip)) >=1 Then 
          lbadFound = true
          badAddresses  = badAddresses  & recip & & vbcrlf 
      End If

    Next i

    If lbadFound Then
       prompt$ = "You sending this mail to one or more black listed email address(es)" & badAddresses & vbcrlf & " Are you sure you want to send it?"
       If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
         Cancel = True
       End If
    End If
```

Comment: I am going to be giving this macro to others to install so so I want to have the black-listed emails contained within the macro rather than having a separate file, but in a way that is easy to read and modify if needed.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. I am getting a compile error at the end of the "bad@address.com", _     The error says "Expected: end of statement"

Comment: please try now, I forgot to put the appends

Comment: Thanks Krishna, it compiles now but the macro still lets me send emails to the addresses on the Checklist.

Comment: please try now, if this doesnt work, can you put in a break point at the compare statement and Debug.print what instr is returning

Comment: I added the break point. recip = "bad@address.com" , checklist = "bad@address.com worst@address.com evil@address.com"

Comment: Could it be that "bad@address.com" is not the same as "bad@address.com worst@address.com evil@address.com" ?

Comment: :) found it, we are using instr incorrectly, please see my edit

Comment: Yes!!! You nailed it! Works great now. One small cosmetic thing is that I get a pop-up for each bad address, how can I make it so I only one pop-up even if there are several bad emails included?

Comment: That didn't seam to work, it didnt give the pop-up or send the email. Is there a way to create an array or list of the bad email addresses found, and then display that array or list in the pop-up message? Say two of the three bad emails existed, can a pop