# Prompt for verifying recipients

Tags: vba, outlook

When sending an email to anyone outside of my business I want a prompt asking for confirmation with all the recipients printed in the prompt.

I tried code from [Outlook VBA to verify recipient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247643/outlook-vba-to-verify-recipient). It does nothing.

I tried multiple things from multiple sites but none give me what I am looking for.

I am using the following code:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim lbadFound  As Boolean
Dim badAddresses As String
lbadFound = False

CheckList = "test@test.nl"

Set Recipients = Item.Recipients
For i = Recipients.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set recip = Recipients.Item(i)

    If InStr(1, LCase(CheckList), LCase(recip)) >= 1 Then
        lbadFound = True
        badAddresses = badAddresses & recip & vbCrLf
    End If

Next i

If lbadFound Then
    prompt$ = "You sending this mail to one or more black listed email address(es)" & badAddresses & vbCrLf & " Are you sure you want to send it?"
    If MsgBox(prompt$, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Address") = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

This code makes use of a checklist. The idea is to fill the checklist with all the e-mails of the company and prompt with an if-statement when the recipient is not in this list (prompting with all mail addresses of the recipients that are not in the checklist).

I also tried this and it will prompt but it prints every item in the xAddress:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
'UpdatebyExtendoffice20180523
Dim xRecipients As Outlook.Recipients
Dim xRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
Dim xPos As Integer
Dim xYesNo As Integer
Dim xPrompt As String
Dim xAddress As String
On Error Resume Next
If Item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub
Set xRecipients = Item.Recipients
xAddress = "example1@gmail.com"
For Each xRecipient In xRecipients
    xPos = InStr(LCase(xRecipient.Address), xAddress)
    If xPos = 0 Then
        xPrompt = "You sending this to " & xAddress & ". Are you sure you want to send it?"
        xYesNo = MsgBox(xPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + 4096, "Kutools for Outlook")
        If xYesNo = vbNo Then Cancel = True
    End If
Next xRecipient
End Sub
```

Comment: What is happening?

Comment: Nothing at all. It will just send the mail anyway.

Comment: Does the prompt come up?  What are some of the example addresses being passed in.  More info is needed, no idea what the `.recipients` collection contains.

Comment: No the prompt won't come up. Ideally it should check every email with the domain of the company.For .recipients it should check the adress of the recipient in the mail.

Comment: The second code does give a prompt. But as stated if I add more mails te be checked:

Comment: It will print the whole array. f.e. "test@test.nl," & "test2@test.nl"

Comment: Also, when I enter a different email in the mail, for example yes@test.nl it will still print I am sending this to test@test.nl even though I didn't put that mail in the recipients.

Comment: In the 2nd code, `If xPos = 0 Then` would check for not found, as `instr(1,"nathan","test")` returns 0

Comment: Nathan hit the nail on the head with recipients collection. You're likely having mismatches between Display Name values of the recipient and actual email address. Is this an exchange server you're working on?  The second set of code is correctly calling out the .Address property of the Recipient item which is why its actually doing something. The first code is almost certainly saying InStr("My Name","myemailaddress@nl.com"). Second code depending on your setup(Exchange vs other) may be returning a different address than you are expecting.  Suggest stepping through while watching locals window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple problems - you are treating `Recipient` object as a string (you pass it to `LCase`, which expects a string) - in that case VBA converts the object to a string by reading the default property (which is most likely `Name`). You need to use `recip.Address` instead.

Are you using Exchange Server? In that case all internal recipients will have address type of "EX" and external recipients "SMTP"

In that case your check must be

```
If recip.AddressEntry.Type = "SMTP" Then
   ...
```

Comment: Yes I am using Exchange Server. I will try out your code. So basically I will only have to add this code after On Error Resume Next and add the code for the prompt to appear in case of SMTP. Is that correct? (And also include the Dim's for recip.Address and Recip.AddressEntry.Type)

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.