# VBA on Outook - prompt user before sending an email and check list

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am trying to help a local school with Outlook and sending emails with a validation check. I have read this article which was helpful ([Outlook VBA to verify recipient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247643/outlook-vba-to-verify-recipient)) but I am hoping there might be a way to extend on this blacklist. The format of the student email addresses is something like this joe.bloggs28@schooldomain.com. So the end of the students last name will always have 2 numbers (which is their cohort year).

Is VBA caplable of a blacklist based on a character string rather than a full email address? So if it contains: 28@schooldomain.com it would then prompt the user and warn them that it is a student email address. There would be several variations of this such as 26@, 27@ and so on.

I am also hoping that within the same VBA script we can have it prompt the user if it's an external email (so @gmail.com, @hotmail.com, etc). This would have to be on the same principal of the above where it would be a specific text string and if the receipents email address contained that then the prompt would be triggered.

The purpose of this is to help the school staff so when sending an email to a student or external person they would get the prompt. The prompt would also need to list the email address(es) that trigger the prompt.

Thanks in advance

Terrence.